# What does "depends $C^{m}$-ly on parameters" mean?

Tags: notation, partial-differential-equations

Context is probably not important. What does it mean to say "$u_{a,b}$ depends $C^{m}$-ly on $a$ and $b$"? I know what it means to say a solution depends continuously on the data (change in solutions is less than or equal to change in data, informally).

Context: $u_{a,b} = u(at, x+bt)$ and $u(x,t)$ solves some PDE.

Comment: $C^m$ typically means that it is $m$ times continuously differentiable--so it has a continuous $m$th derivative--a stronger statement than merely continuous.

Comment: The partial derivatives of $u_{a,b}$ of order up to $m$ with respect to $a$ and/or $b$ exist and are continuous.